# undefined method constantize in rake task

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run this code"

```
FACTORY = %w(ProcessedTransaction Chargeback).freeze
 FACTORY.constantize.each do |factory|
   factory.public_send(:delete_all)
   end
 end
```

But I get this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method`constantize' for #`

Do you know how I can solve the issue?

Comment: What is `constantize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby uppercased variables are constants by default so you can't call `constantize` on it. In your case it's just an array so this should work:

```
FACTORY = %w(ProcessedTransaction Chargeback).freeze
FACTORY.each do |factory|
  factory.constantize.public_send(:delete_all)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [String#constantize](https://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize) only on strings but you are calling it on array `FACTORY`.

Remove `FACTORY.constantize` and add `factory.constantize.public_send(:delete_all)`

Also make sure you have [ActiveSupport::Inflector](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector) required